# ASP.NET Session variable becomes null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

My solution explorer (if helps):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdhDz.png

When i click on account button(with href to account.aspx), it redirects me to login.aspx because not authorised.

on my login.aspx.cs(after they click login), i have

```
Session["hi"] = "hello";
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("username");
cookie.Value = UName.Text;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UName.Text, false);
```

on the account.aspx.cs i have

```
if (Session["hi"] != null)
{
    Literal1.Text = Session["hi"].ToString();
    Literal1.Text += "<br><br><br>";
}
```

Why does it not show anything? I tried all sorts of ways to display this session, didnt work,
for some reason Session["hi"] is null.

Comment: Are u sure `account` is called after code in `login` has been processed? Can u put breakpoint in both places?

Comment: Why do you create **username** cookie since you are using **FormsAuthentication**? Post the content inside `~/LoggedIn/web.config`.

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>'

Comment: @Mikiku Post the content of `<authentication>` inside `~/web.config`

Comment: is `<allow users="Role"/>` missing?

Comment: BTW, the check on `Session["hi"]` will blow up in an `Exception`. You should use `if (Session.ContainsKey("hi")) { ... }` instead.

Comment: @pid `Session["hi"]` also works.

Comment: @Nanosoft: Oh, wait... you're right! It's those pesky `Dictionary<>` that don't return `null` for non-existent keys. Just got carried away :)

Comment: I only have <deny users="?"/> in <authentication> in the LoggedIN web config

Comment: You don't do `Session["hi"].ToString()` but `(string)Session["hi"]`

Comment: @async tried both ways, its not the problem

Comment: @Mikiku ***Post the content of <authentication> inside ~/web.config***

Comment: @win <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you need to set [AuthenticationSection.Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.authenticationsection.mode.aspx) to `mode="Forms"`.

By default, it is Window mode.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
     timeout="2880" 
     cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

### How to create Principal Object

Once authenticated user is requested a page, you need to retrieve auth ticket from cookie, and create a Principal object.

### Global.asax.cs

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpCookie decryptedCookie = 
      Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
      FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

   var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
   var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

   HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal =HttpContext.Current.User;
}
```

### Usage

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{

}
```

Comment: but i have
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>
        </authentication>

Comment: Look like you do not create **IPrincipal** object on **AuthenticateRequest**. I updated my answer.

Comment: ehhh, looks hard for my 1st assignment ever ;d Thanks